# jqgrid custom sorting with duplicates

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a jQgrid column which would show data as in the below example.

1. 5 of 10
2. 2 of 2
3. 5 of 5
4. 2 of 10.... etc 
    
   I wanna implement a custom sorting which would sort first based on the number before 'of' and then for duplicates it should use the number after the 'of'.

I have implemented the main sort using the following function.

```
sorttype: function (cellValue, cellObject) {
                        var sortValueArr = cellValue.split(" ");
                        return parseInt(sortValueArr[0]);
                        //return [parseInt(sortValueArr[0]), parseInt(sortValueArr[2])];
                    }
```

But am stuck up implementing the secondary-sort-for-duplicates. I tried it with the commented line above. But it is not working.

Please help me out.

The output required is

1. 2 of 2
2. 2 of 10
3. 5 of 5
4. 5 of 10

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's not a *pretty* answer, but you if you know a hard maximum for the second number, you can run it as a float.  For example, if you can be sure that the second number won't get above, say, 1000, you might use the following

```
sorttype: function (cellValue, cellObject)
{
    var sortValueArr = cellValue.split(" ");
    return (parseFloat(sortValueArr[0]) + parseFloat(sortValueArr[2])/1000);
}
```

Comment: I tried some similar logic, but am week in algorithms for that matter. I couldn't figure out a expression for sorting this...
The one suggested here wouldn't work, coz, considering a max of 10,
and data points 1 of 9, 2 of 2...   would give, 2 of 2 first and 1 of 9 second...
Also, i tried reversing the result.. But that din work as well with the actual data...

Comment: You just do standard jqgrid sort on floats.  1 of 9 gives you 1.009, while 2 of 2 gives you 2.002, and so forth.  Is this not what you are getting?